# is it possible the Consumer won't receive the message from SQS even though ApproximateReceiveCount is less than Maximum receives of the SQS?

Tags: amazon-sqs

I need to do specific action on receiving a message at its last retry(consumer fails to process the message). So, can I rely on ApproximateReceiveCount attribute to do specific action? As it is approximate receive count and count could be eventual consistent because of distibuted queue.

I am thinking of a scenario

1. Consumer receives the message ApproximateReceiveCount  less than max receives, but in actual it should have been equal to the max receives count, as message had been retried to the max receive count.
2. Now relying on ApproximateReceiveCount  I would be expecting the message will retried one more time but in actual max receive count has already reached, so my tigger to specific action wont work here.